# How can I create an html table, with unknown number of columns per row, get the columns to be aligned, and have an id for each cell/row?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, html-table

I'm trying to build a table with divs, and being able to get an id associated with each cell of the table. For this, I'm using angularJS, and I'm trying to get ng-repeat to do what I want.

When using an HTML table, we can use colspan to define the columns so even if the number of columns is different, the layout still show an aligned table. But what if you don't know if the next row will have 2 columns or 4 columns? how can you control that? That's why I'm using div's, so I can play with their width, according with the number of columns I need.

Here's the fiddle I'm working on at the moment:
http://jsfiddle.net/xEyJZ/239/

Any help would be appreciated, as my problem is how to set the divs, so that the table looks aligned. If you check the fiddle, you can see that none of the columns are aligned. Ideally the last row should be centered, the row with two columns should be evenly split across the row, etc.

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
<table border="1">
    <tr ng-repeat="person in people" ng-class="rowClass(person)">
        <td>
            <div style="float:left;outline:black solid thin;" ng-click="test(person, 0)">{{ person.col0 }}</div>
            <div style="float:left;outline:black solid thin;" ng-hide="person.cols < 1" ng-click="test(person, 1)">{{ person.col1 }}</div>
            <div style="float:left;outline:black solid thin;" ng-hide="person.cols < 2" ng-click="test(person, 2)">{{ person.col2 }}</div>
            <div style="float:left;outline:black solid thin;" ng-hide="person.cols < 3" ng-click="test(person, 3)">{{ person.col3 }}</div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Can anyone shed some light, please?

Comment: So the title of your question has nothing to do with what you actually want.

Comment: he's clearly new here, rather than give him a negative experience by voting him down, maybe point him to some guidelines. This place can be such a turn-off for new-comers. posting guidelines http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Are you always going to have the `person.cols` property... or are you eventually going to have a `cols` array or items?

Comment: The person.cols will always be there, and it's an integer. I added the person.cols to add me with the logic, the only thing that really matters is the data in person.col0, person.col1, person.col2, person.col3

Comment: Right... but wouldn't you want to store person.col0, person.col1... etc in something more scalable like `person.cols = ['col1','col2','col3']`?

Comment: I played around a while and I got your divs aligned with some css and pixel settings. I hope the Fiddle helps you: http://jsfiddle.net/jyrkim/xEyJZ/244/  About the Fiddle, I didn't post it as answer because I wasn't 100% sure is the Fiddle providing a good enough answer for you, but in any case I got those divs aligned; so the Fiddle is on the right track - let's put it that way :-)

Comment: @entropic: people is an array of persons, so I think I'm storing more or less what you're referring to/

Comment: @jyrkim : Thanks, looks quite good and it's working :) I thought you would need to use ng-style in order to work properly but apparently not. Thanks!!

Comment: @bluestrattos No you aren't.  I'm talking about storing it like this: `var people = [{ id: 0, cols: ['1','2',3'] }, { id: 1, cols: ['1', '2', '3', '4'] }, ... ];`

Comment: @bluestrattos Yep, you are right, ng-style could be used here as well, and I think it would be a more appropriate solution, because it makes the code clearer as it point outs when a controller's $scope value is used in the view. I'm quite new with AngularJS so I'm learning too :-)

Comment: @entropic oh, I got what you were saying. In this specific example, the max number of columns will always be 4, but yes, your suggestion does make sense, and it does make sense from a code practices point of view.

Comment: @jyrkim I was looking at your jsfiddle with fresh eyes, and it's not quite what I'm looking for. The row with a single column, for instance, the width should be the width of there entire table, or the two columns rows, the cells aren't being split where each cell would have 50% of with of the table. But I'm adapting your idea of doing the calculations inside the width tag, to get the cells to behave like there was a colspan tag. Thanks for the idea.  I'm also quite new in this AngularJS framework :)

Comment: @bluestrattos Wow, your solution sounds very interesting and neat too :-) It'd be very dynamic way of printing table cells. Actually, it might be handy to use table cells(td elements) for that purpose and give a percentage (%) width instead of pixel width for each cell while the table has its own width set. That would probably require some extra processing in the controller before the view prints the table with each cell.

Comment: @bluestrattos Well, on the other hand I'm not quite sure about the last bit because I'm quite newbie with AngularJS so the question how to use the controller and the view in optimal way in this question is still unclear to me.

Comment: @jyrkim Thanks for your help :-) I managed to build a table with divs, where the widths are calculated according with the specified number of columns. The code itself still needs optimisation, like suggested by @ entropic, but I'll leave the updated jsfiddle for future reference: http://jsfiddle.net/Bluestrattos/xEyJZ/248/

Comment: @bluestrattos looks good, I'm impressed :-) I'll give you an upvote if you put it as an answer :-)

Comment: @bluestrattos Does it have to be divs, or are you OK with a table based solution? Edit: Nevermind - I see you've found your answer.

Comment: @entropic Thanks anyway. And also thanks for the tip to do the storing.

Answer (score 1):

[@jyrkim](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2048391/jyrkim) Thanks for your help.
I managed to build a table with `<div>`s, where the widths are calculated according with the specified number of columns.
The code itself still needs optimisation, like suggested by [@entropic](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3712036/entropic), but here's the updated jsfiddle for future reference:

[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Bluestrattos/xEyJZ/248/)